# How to mix select and delete in a Slick transaction

Tags: scala, transactions, slick, slick-3.0

Why does it not work to combine a SELECT and a DELETE statement in a Slick query? as in:

```
 val query = (for {
     item <- SomeTable
     _ <- OtherTable.filter(_.id === item.id).delete
 } yield ()).transactionally
```

> "Cannot resolve symbol 'transactionally'"

(without `.transactionally`, it is a `Query[Nothing, Nothing, Seq]`, if that helps)
while the two actions work separately:

```
 val query = (for {
     item <- SomeTable
 } yield ()).transactionally
```

,

```
 val query = (for {
     _ <- OtherTable.filter(_.id === 2).delete
 } yield ()).transactionally
```

Comment: Try `item <- SomeTable.result`. I can't get second example to compile, `SomeTable` is a `TableQuery` right?

Comment: I tried. Then I cannot use `item` to filter a second table, delete or not (I updated the first snippet to show case this). The real query is more complicated.

Comment: @insan-e `SomeTable` is a `TableQuery`, yes. You could add a `filter` after it too. You can chain select statements that way with `for`, or delete statements, but not both apparently.

Comment: With `item <- SomeTable.result` you'll get a `Seq[ModelRow]` (a list of rows from `SomeTable`). You have to say something like `OtherTable.filter(_.id.inSet(item.map(_.id)).delete`.

Comment: @insan-e Seems to be it! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so this is a classic example of mixing `DBIO` with `Query`.

In your first case:

```
val query = (for {
     item <- SomeTable // this is `Query`
     _ <- OtherTable.filter(_.id === item.id).delete // this is `DBIO`
 } yield ()).transactionally
```

Obviously for `DML` you can use only actions (`Query` is for `DQL` - being simply `SELECT`).

So first thing is - change your code to use only `DBIO`s. Below example is incorrect.

```
val query = (for {
     item <- SomeTable.result // this is `DBIO` now
     _ <- OtherTable.filter(_.id === item.id).delete // but this won't work !!
 } yield ()).transactionally
```

OK, we are nearly there - the problem is that it doesn't compile. What you need to do is to be aware that now this part:

```
item <- SomeTable.result
```

returns `Seq` of your `SomeTable` case class (which among other things contains your `id`).

So let's take into account:

```
val query = (for {
     items <- SomeTable.result // I changed the name to `items` to reflect it's plural nature
     _ <- OtherTable.filter(_.id.inset(items.map(_.id))).delete // I needed to change it to generate `IN` query
 } yield ()).transactionally
```

Comment: I had to split things - do the selects in one query and put that query + the delete in a transaction - but ultimately it worked when I added `result`. Thanks for the detailed explanation. It is not easy to inspect object types in IDE, and I was mixing things up with the syntax for joins.